# onBlur input event does not work when clicking on the link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onblur

I have following code:

```
<AutosizeInput
    key={id}
    name="title"
    value={value}
    onBlur={saveToDataBase}
    className="input"
    spellCheck="false"
/>
```

I want to call a function when user click outside of input. Everything working as expected except one case: if user click on the link on the same page (outside of input) onBlur event does not occures and input stays focused.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Clicking on the link neither refresh the page nor redirect to another route?

Comment: You can try this maybe, add to all links **onClick** event as follows : - **getElementById(‘inputField’).blur()** and of course add an id to the inputField

Comment: It is "redirect" to other page: i using React Router to create single page application and link opens a new page in modal window